# setHours is not a function when converting time from string

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to compare a time in string format to the current time. I've tried setting up two Date objects and calling .Now() on both of them, then on one of them adjusting the time to the time that is in string format by splitting it and parsing both the hours and minutes to integers, but I get the following error:

> setHours is not a function

The 'cutoff' value I'm using is '15:00' and when following in the debugger I can see this splits in to split[0] = 15 and split[1] = 00 (this is before they are parsed into integers.

```
 var cutoff = data.CutOff;
 var split = cutoff.split(":");
 var today = Date.now();
 var hours = parseInt(split[0]);
 var min = parseInt(split[1]);
 today.setHours(hours, min);
 if (Date.now() < today) {
     // Do Something
 }
```

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now): "The Date.now() method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC."

Comment: Your `today` is not a Date object, rather its a number (the milliseconds till now from epoch), and correctly you cannot call the setHours method on a number. To do so, you need a Date object instance. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to do `new Date()` as opposed to `Date.now()`

`new Date` creates a `Date` instance which allows you to access the `Date` methods.

`Date.now()` method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Comment: Thanks - how will that work with the comparison though? Is there a way I can create a date object with today's time?

Comment: Just new Date()? On it's own?